# Parsing/Unmarshaling query strings which passing arrays as parameters in Java

Tags: java, url, query-string, jersey, kendo-ui

Is there a way to **Parse/Unmarshall** query strings which passing arrays as parameters in Java into Map or custom class?

URL example:

localhost:8080/app/ws/categories?take=10&skip=10&page=2&pageSize=10&filter[logic]=and&filter[filters][0][field]=company_id&filter[filters][0][operator]=eq&filter[filters][0][value]=1513

I need to parse **filter** parameter in something like this:

```Java
public class Filter {

private String logic;
private List<Filters> filters;

public class Filters {
    private String field;
    private String operator;
    private String value;
    }
}
```

One more point - I'm using Jersey here, maybe it has possibility to **Parse/Unmarshall** @QueryParam using **Jersey's** tools?

Anyway any other Java solutions will be OK too.

Comment: Even if it exists... how would you use it from standard Java code (without lots of lines of reflection)?

Comment: Reflection is not an issue present days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do it utilizing @BeanParam from JAXRS 2.0 spec

```
public PageableResponse<PatientBundleType> getPatientBundles(@BeanParam final PageableBeanParam paging)
{
    ...
}

public class PageableBeanParam
{
    public PageableBeanParam(@Context final UriInfo uriInfo)
    {

        for (Entry<String, List<String>> param : params.entrySet())
        {
            String key = param.getKey();
            String value = param.getValue().iterator().next();

            if ("pageSize".equals(key))
            {
                setPageSize(Integer.valueOf(value));
            }

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest 2 things :

Either you want to perform a GET, then to keep a RESTful approach, I would have an Url like :
localhost:8080/app/ws/categories?take/10/skip/10/page/2/pageSize/10/filter/logic/and/ ...etc

Or POST is acceptable, and I would send JSON payload

Comment: Unfortunately I can't afford this solution, because I'm using Kendo UI Grid which is querying REST services at the specified at the question format and I can't modify their core code in some reasons.

Comment: I would move that this is not a RESTful approach. @Dzmitry has, IMHO, the correct format.